# Python: create combinations of two columns containing lists as their value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I have a dataframe with lists in its columns and I am trying to figure out most efficient way to find the combination of the two lists -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[['a','b','c'],['l','m']],[['d','e','f'],['n','o']]],columns = ['col1','col2'])
```

Now the output in this case would be -

```
     col1   col2
0   [a, l]  [a, m]
1   [b, l]  [b, m]
2   [c, l]  [c, m]
3   [d, n]  [d, o]
4   [e, n]  [e, o]
5   [f, n]  [f, o]
```

I tried iterating through each row and then apply itertools.combinations. But it's crashing my system for higher number of rows in the dataframe. Can you please suggest me any efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: at what number of rows does it crash?

Comment: The problem seems more with how are you iterating ? The best way would beto not keep any cache of the modified data for a given row. After doing the combination, just flush that row out and then move for next row processing. Also, if dataframe size is too big compared to what RAM your system has(allocated to your process), then it will fail with OOO anyway. The way to handle that is to chunk your file and process one chunk at a time and concatenate at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `itertools.product` with `numpy.reshape`:

```
from itertools import product

print (pd.DataFrame(np.reshape([list(product(a,b))
                                for a,b in df.to_numpy()],
                               (-1,2,2)).tolist()))

        0       1
0  [a, l]  [a, m]
1  [b, l]  [b, m]
2  [c, l]  [c, m]
3  [d, n]  [d, o]
4  [e, n]  [e, o]
5  [f, n]  [f, o]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#) to get your output :

```
from itertools import product, chain, tee, islice

col1, col2 = tee(chain.from_iterable(product(col1, col2) 
                                     for col1, col2 
                                     in df.to_numpy()), 
                 2)

# Here we get alternate rows
col1 = islice(col1, None, None, 2)

col2 = islice(col2, 1, None, 2)

pd.DataFrame(zip(col1, col2), columns=["col1", "col2"])

    col1    col2
0   (a, l)  (a, m)
1   (b, l)  (b, m)
2   (c, l)  (c, m)
3   (d, n)  (d, o)
4   (e, n)  (e, o)
5   (f, n)  (f, o)
```